# quarkus dev mode for CLI, how to restart app

Tags: java, command-line-interface, quarkus

I just created a sample Quarkus CLI app. When I run it in dev mode, pressing [enter] does not restart the application.

Steps to reproduce:

I am using the quarkus CLI, on macOS Big Sur, default Terminal app. I generate a default cli app with the following command:

```
quarkus create cli --group-id=test --artifact-id=test --maven --java --code
```

Then, once I am inside the test folder, I run:

```
quarkus dev
```

The example code runs and dev mode stays waiting for changes, but if I update the sample code and press [enter] on the terminal as described in the [quarkus guide for CLI apps](https://quarkus.io/guides/command-mode-reference), the app is not rerun.

I also tried maven directly as suggested on the guide:

```
mvn compile quarkus:dev
```

But the result is the same.

The example generated is very simple, and uses Quarkus 2.0.1 with the picocli extension. Works fine when compiled and run standalone.

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is a bug in 2.0 cli where `create cli` does not create a cli but just the standard app. Thus it won't reload until you hit localhost:8080.

it will be fixed in next version. sorry for inconvenience.

In the mean time you can use https://quarkus.io/guides/command-mode-reference which explains the minimal code and dependencies needed for a Quarkus cli.

Comment: It created a CLI app using the picocli extension. I can `quarkus build --native` and run the generated native cli app as expected, no http server running. The only problem seems to be the [Enter] key not working as described in dev mode. Is the picocli extension responsible for breaking the "re-run on [enter] key support" in dev mode?

Comment: I added a `QuarkusMain` annotation to the generated command and implemented the `run` method as described in the picocli guide, which is very similar to the command-mode-reference guide, still the [Enter] key doesn't re-run the app in dev mode in my environment.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with Quarkus 2.0.1.

I do `quarkus create cli -a mycli; cd mycli; quarkus dev` and whatever changes I do shows up when i press enter.

Can you check what quarkus version outputs and if it is not  latest 2.0.1 please update and try again. if still failing open issue with the steps you do and your exact environment (operating system, terminal, shell, etc.) as they affect console output.

Comment: Refreshed quarkus cli and ran the same command as you posted. I get Quakus 2.0.1. No matter if I run `quarkus dev` or `./mvnw quarkus:dev`, I still have the same result: after pressing enter I just get a blank line in my terminal, quarkus dev never restarts my app, even after making changes to the source code.

Comment: I've created an issue in Github: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/18719

Comment: This issue is no longer present in 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project have any tests? The picocli project created by the cli doesn't by default (yet?).

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/18700 should fix your issue (behavior of dev mode for projects without tests).